# NSPredicate Sort Array and Order DESC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, filter, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have an `NSMutableArray` containing `TBPosts` that I would like to filter in descending order according to the `commentsCount` and `likesCount` of the `TBPost`.

Initially, the first object in the filtered array will be the object with the largest number of comments and likes, which can be worked out by adding the two together. So I tried the following query and receive an Unable to Parse error. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
[posts filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"post.commentsCount + post.likesCount DESC"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filtering is not sorting. You are using the wrong method.

Using a comparator, it would look like this:

```
[posts sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id p1, id p2) {
    if (p1.commentsCount + p1.likesCount < p2.commentsCount + p2.likesCount)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    if (p1.commentsCount + p1.likesCount > p2.commentsCount + p2.likesCount)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

Comment: Does a sort descriptor have the ability to do what I want?

Comment: I am just checking the docs — I usually prefer comparators, but sortDescriptor will do.

Comment: //The following should do it. No need to do all cases
[posts sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id p1, id p2) {
        return (p1.commentsCount + p1.likesCount) < (p2.commentsCount + p2.likesCount) ;
    }];

Comment: @Komposr: this can be harmful. `NSComparisionResult` is a typdefed integer, with values 0f `-1,0,1` while relational operators return `0`or `1`. So your code won't cover the NSOrderedSame case.

Comment: Isn't it the case that with NSOrderedSame, it doesn't matter which one is returned ? Like trying to sort: 0,1,2,2,3...

Comment: this will result in a unstable sorting. you cant know, if it might matters. maybe one wants to sort 2 arrays and latter check the percentage of how much they changed in comparison. than t would matter, that on object with property 2 and a second with the same value got reordered or not.

Comment: You may be right. Gimme an example with arrays to sort and I'll check. The example above is comparing integer/long. There are other ways of doing the comparison using the options method:                                NSArray  *arr1;
    [arr1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];   //Where NSNumericSearch can be replaced with whatever is suitable.

Comment: `compare:options:` is a NSString method, so it will only work if `obj1` and `obj2` are NSStrings. But if they were, they wouldn't had a property `commentsCount`, hence this won't work in this situation. anyway: why are you open up an discussion on a nearly 2 years old thread?